# Scraping tables from Excel files into R

Tags: r, excel, screen-scraping

I have several excel files (*.xlsx) and I want to import them into R, but each file has 6 to 7 tables in a single sheet, separated by chunks of text, like the picture.

[image]

I know how to import several excel files using a loop, but my issue is I cannot figure out how select each of the tables distributed along each sheet, avoiding the rows with text, and bind them. Also, each table from each excel file starts in a different cell, so I cannot just define a coordinate (a specific cell) to import the tables. Every excel file is different in amount of rows. I'll appreciate any help.

For instance, the above picture is about Maryland (an US State), and I want to transform that into what is presented in the following picture:

[image]

This is a toy file to anyone able to help me: [LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2a8cyja0mjtfsc3/Example-stackoverflow1.xlsx?dl=0)
Thanks!

Comment: How about you import into a dataframe and then delete all rows that only have content in the first column?

Comment: Scrapping the tables? Just delete them, not like recycling a car :)

Comment: In addition to what @MarioNiepel wrote. You might want to split up this one sheet intoe several tables then. And the split woudl happen whenever there is an empty row.

Comment: An alternative, but I don't remember exactly anymore, is to format each table as a real table in Excel (there's a special function for it in Excel) and then import it with the openxlsx package.IIRC, this package offers to catch individual tables from a spreadsheet. But maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Thaks @MarioNiepel, but how can I identify the rows I need to delete, because each one starts with different letters/words? Also, I cannot just delete rows and binding with the below table, because not always there are the same amount (and name) of columns, as I show in the picture. (There are several files like this, that's why I need automatize the process)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image of the data you showed, it seems that all rows can be removed where the second column has an NA? In that case subsetting in base R is pretty straightforward:

```
test <- test[!is.na(test[,2]),]
```

Quick explanation:

test[ ,2] --> evaluate all rows in column 2

is.na(test[ ,2]) --> return TRUE if cell is NA

!is.na(test[ ,2]) --> return FALSE if cell is NA

test[!is.na(test[,2]),] --> all rows of test dataframe where cell in col 2 is not NA

Again, based on the data you showed this should work. But hard to work out w/o true sample date.

Comment: Thanks. I think is a clever idea to take the rows. But I still have the issue to bind the rows, because the order of the columns are irregular. As you can see in the picture, even when most of the tables have the same number of column, the order and name are not always the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think that anybody can give you more concrete advice based on an image of a fraction of the data. Please set up a small toy example of the data you are working with, what you have tried, what you current output is, and what your desired output is.

Comment: You're right Mario. I added a xlsx file and a picture of what I'm looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: I took a look at the file and I am actually working on a similar project right now. I think there is really nothing to do other than tackling the problems one by one. Look through the first column to identify all the year/state combinations. After that try to identifiy the block of data that belongs to that year/state combo and extract. Then combine all the extracted blocks by matching up the variables in the columns.

Comment: Thanks, anyway. I'll give it a chance to your ideas.